# Angular is not start locally after build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron, electron-builder

I start my project with electron + angular
I have that file structure

```
-build
---icon.ico
-data
--- {some json files for data and will be updated from splash screen}
-app
---{angular app build files index.html ... etc}
-index.html ( that is the splash screen and the data caller)
-main.js
-renderer.js
-package.json
```

the angular app is running from my Mac but after building is not running at all in windows even the html page is not loading giving error of

Error Type: window.require is not a function

> noted : that I tried to remove the nomodule and type="module" and my base is  
> and I rebuild the app in windows environment as well

The application is loading the splash screen and once it opens the angular built app its giving white screen and when I activate my debugger (openDevTools()) I found that error I mentioned before

SplashScreen index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Splash Screen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="./assets/images/LOGO-WHITE.svg" width="136" class="logo" />
    <img src="./assets/images/close.png" alt="close" id="btnClose" title="Close Application">
    <h1><img src="./assets/images/pac-white.svg" width="60" class="logo" style="margin-right: 10px;" /><i class="fas fa-ghost"></i>PAC</h1>
    <h2>Project Allowances Calculator</h2>
    <p class="slogan">
      some paragraph 
    </p>
    <p class="loading-report" id="loadingText">Loading ....</p>
    <div class="author">
      <h6><strong>Developed with <span style="margin-right: 5px;"></span> By </strong> Mohamed Abdelall</h6>
      <h6><strong>Version </strong> <span id="version">1.0.0-beta 2021</span></h6>
    </div>
    <script>
        require('./renderer.js');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the angular app index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>PAC</title>
    <base href="./" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.c34bab37f7665a54cf19.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime.a486bb3e6b9b6ae69e10.js"></script>
    <script src="es2015-polyfills.c2e8e9452bd0df30144a.js"></script>
    <script src="polyfills.c8a8d38b17913b302028.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.d500224ea0d13a070749.js"></script>
    <script src="main.fdaeb3cc924284b133f4.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the angular version

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.10
Node: 14.15.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.10
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.10
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      7.3.10
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.10
@schematics/angular               7.3.10
@schematics/update                0.13.10
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

and here the loading code for the angular app in electron main.js

```
mainScreen = new BrowserWindow({
    title: "CalcApp",
    width: 720,
    height: 560,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    },
  });

  mainScreen.openDevTools();
  mainScreen.loadFile("./app/index.html");
```

Comment: Please check if you have any imports from main to renderer. Or if you are using any main package in renderer without node intergration.

Comment: there is no issue for that the main problem is angular app is not even loading from normal browser launching